# Monotouch.Dialog and iAds

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, iad, monotouch.dialog

I'm playing with iAds. I want to add it to an app that is basically a bunch of Monotouch.Dialog views.

Is the best practise to add a **UIViewController**, then add a **ADBannerView** and a **Monotouch.Dialog** to it , or should I add the **iAds** view to the **Monotouch.Dialog** ViewController?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a wrapper ViewController that works nicely, just pass in the main app's view like a TabBar or SplitView etc and use IADViewController as the RootViewCOntroller:

```
     public partial class IADViewController : UIViewController
{
    private UIViewController _anyVC;
    private MonoTouch.iAd.ADBannerView _ad;

    public IADViewController (UIViewController anyVC)
    {
        _anyVC = anyVC;
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        View.AddSubview (_anyVC.View);


        if (Common.Device.Is6AtLeast && Social.IsiAdCountry) {

            try {
                _ad = new MonoTouch.iAd.ADBannerView (MonoTouch.iAd.ADAdType.Banner);
                _ad.Hidden = true;
                _ad.FailedToReceiveAd += HandleFailedToReceiveAd;
                _ad.AdLoaded += HandleAdLoaded;
                View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                _anyVC.View.Frame = View.Bounds;
                View.AddSubview (_ad);
            } catch {
            }
        } else {
            Resize ();
        }
    }

    public override void DidRotate (UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        base.DidRotate (fromInterfaceOrientation);
        Resize ();
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
        Resize ();
    }

    void Resize ()
    {

        UIView.Animate (.25,
            () => {
                if (_ad !=null && _ad.Hidden == false) {
                    _anyVC.View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, this.View.Bounds.Width, this.View.Bounds.Height - _ad.Frame.Height);
                } else {
                    _anyVC.View.Frame = View.Bounds;
                }
            });
        if(_ad!=null)
           _ad.Frame = new RectangleF (0, _anyVC.View.Bounds.Height, this.View.Bounds.Width, _ad.Frame.Height);
    }

    void HandleAdLoaded (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_ad == null)
            return;
        _ad.Hidden = false;
        Resize ();
    }

    void HandleFailedToReceiveAd (object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_ad == null)
            return;
        _ad.Hidden = true;
        Resize ();
    }
}
```